# Discussions in Trello?

Tags: trello, project-management

I'm starting to adopt Trello for Project Management as a supplement to Basecamp as the more that I use Basecamp, the more that I'm discovering that it's just not a great tool for managing the intricate details of a Project. It's great for conversations and file sharing related to a Project, but you just don't get a good sense of progress or status like you do with Trello.

I really don't like the idea of adding "yet another tool" to the mix, so I was wondering if there was any way to make Trello viable for the discussion and file sharing aspects of Basecamp that we like? Or should we continue to use a similar but separate tool for these things and proceed with Trello for specific project details?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a couple of highly-focused, best-of-breed, online apps/sites together as we've found it to be highly productive, we're using a mixture of Trello, Dropbox and a custom in-house app for managing different aspects of our projects.

**Conversations:**
I can't speak to Basecamp as we've never used it, the conversation aspect is the one we need least, though we use Trello's comments for basic conversations, not sure how intricate your needs are here.

**Tasks:**
We use Trello for assigning tasks to people and monitoring their progress with checklists. Trello also has a iPhone app (important to us for easy on-the-road connectivity).

**File sharing:**
Dropbox provides our file-sharing needs and the Trello-Dropbox integration looks promising (though we haven't yet started using it). Dropbox also has an iPhone app (again, useful for us, we're big fans of iPhone apps).

In short, this has let us be much more efficient and productive as the apps/sites are more targeted at a specific need (& more intuitive), the information is accessible anywhere (even on the road) and synced automatically.

Comment: Are you just using e-mail/phone/verbal communication for conversations? Is that being tracked anywhere? Or is it just an in-house solution?

Comment: @JeremyPrivett - Trello for communication between team members and in-house app/email for communication to clients.

Answer (score 0):

Trello and Google Drive Integrate seamlessly for our marketing company's needs. We use  spreadsheets to track the progress of campaigns and pieces of campaigns, and Trello is the perfect fit for fleshing out who does what and when it's due.

With needs of each project being markedly more different than many other verticals, it gives us the ability to be lean (incorporate freelancers) as well as move quickly to make changes.